# How can i append a program to another and then run it?

Tags: c, generics

I have a little program in mind:

```
void main(void)
{
 printf("Password");
 gets(pass);
 if(!strcmp(pass,"Something"))
   //execute program in the same binary
 else
  printf("Wrong password");
}
```

I need a password to run a program, the program must be in the same executable, and considering that i don't have the source code the idea is to append the second program to the first.

I take some action in my own program and then i run the second program.

¿How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it's going to be that easy to stitch binaries together.  Do they *have* to be a single executable?

If not, then a very close approimxation is to use one of the [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) functions, assuming you're working under *nix.

Comment: Yes, they must be in 1 binary, thank you for the "exec" tip but I know how to use them.

Comment: @Vaul: Then this is going to be very, very difficult!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in (anything close) to the way you seem to want. You *can* manage to do it, but it's a fair amount of work. Basically, you have to concatenate the two programs together, with yours first so it's the one that will execute. Your program will then have to extract the other to a temporary file, execute it, and then delete that temporary file after it's done (or, if available, use OS functions to ensure it's deleted automatically).

Also note that this is extremely fragile on a number of levels -- a hacker who knows what he's doing will probably break your attempt at security in less time than it took you to do it to start with.

Comment: I know the security fault, it's only a concept. Make a temporary file should not be so hard, just calculate the size of the A program, then copy the second from A size to FEOF and execute the temporary.

But anyone can copy the temporary and I would like to cipher it within the first one to avoid copy (For example)

Comment: An alternate method would be to add your code as an additional text section to the existing executable, then alter the entry point to point into your code.  Your code can then jump to the original entry point.

Comment: That would be great, may I use assembler? I think that i can une something like "goto X byte" and follow in that point, I'm searching a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `system` code like this

```
system("binary_code.exe")
```

It might be preferrable to specify the path to the `binary_code.exe` but .... what happens if the external program is removed... you need to handle that and take it into account.

Also, you are asking for trouble by using the obsolete `gets` code which is buffer exploitable... use `fgets` instead!